# Perform preg_replace with html tags inside the search string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a text where I need to perform a string replacement only if it matches whole words.

I am using below code

```
$new_subject = preg_replace( '/\b'. $find .'\b' , $replacement , $subject )
```

(E-g)

```
$subject = "a brown-fox jumps over the lazy dog";
$find = "brown-fox";
$replacement = "Brown Fox";
```

so After preg_replace I get

```
$new_subject = "a Brown Fox jumps over the lazy dog".
```

But I am not getting to know, how to perform perform the same operation with below subjects.

```
$subject = "a <b>brown</b>-fox jumps over the lazy dog" 
$subject = "a <b>brown</b>-<span>fox</span> jumps over the lazy dog" 
$subject = "a bro<b>wn</b>-fo<mark>x</mark> jumps over the lazy dog"
```

below are the replaced texts respectively

```
$new_subject = "a <b>Brown</b> Fox jumps over the lazy dog"
$new_subject = "a <b>Brown</b> <span>Fox</span> jumps over the lazy dog"
$new_subject = "a Bro<b>wn</b> Fo<mark>x</mark> jumps over the lazy dog"
```

Any suggestion/idea which gives me a direction to proceed ?

Comment: Is your replacement always of the same length as the find phrase?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew not necessarily. The length may vary

Comment: I think you're going to have to do a bit of work to get this to work (and I don't see a regex getting it done, you could match it but not replace). I think this could be a starting point, https://3v4l.org/ZPCno. This also assumes the term never has a space in it.